# Big spaces between widgets in Blogger

Tags: html, css, blogger

I have a problem regarding my blogger website. There are annoying spaces above some widgets.

1) On a post page (for example), the blog post date does not align with my left and right sidebar. I would like the left sidebar (search box), the post (date, title etc.) and the right sidebar (black box) to be evenly aligned at top.

2) At the very bottom of the page, there are credit links (© text, about, disclaimer, contact etc.) that are also quite far down from the rest of the content. Again, I would like that space to be omitted so all looks evenly aligned.

I would be really thankful is somebody could help me with this! :) Thanks, Eva

Comment: uds-searchControl is a hidden search result, this pushes the header down

Comment: @Grumpy Yes, this seems to be the problem. Is it possible to remove it?

Comment: use css display:none; to hide and display:block when need to be visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the blog post date does not align with my left and right sidebar

Remove the top margin here:

```
.widget {
   margin: 30px 0;
   _margin: 0 0 10px;
}
```

> At the very bottom of the page …

Remove some of the top padding here

```
.footer-inner {
    padding: 30px 15px;
}
```

and perhaps bottom padding here:

```
.main-inner {
    padding-top: 35px;
    padding-bottom: 65px;
}
```

Comment: This didn't quite work (I cannot find .widget anywhere in my css template), but thanks